# Call controller with href on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm trying to call controller with href, but I'm getting error, I need pass a parameter.
Im doing like this

```
<a href="{{ link_to_action('StoriesController@destroy', $story->id) }}" class="delete"><i class="material-icons" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
```

Controller Code

```
public function destroy(Story $story)
    {
        $story = Story::find($id);
        $story->delete();

        return redirect('/stories')->with('success', 'Historic Removed');
    }
```

Error Missing required parameters for Route: stories.destroy -> [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnn5X.png)

Comment: "_but I'm getting error_" What error?

Comment: Put your error here for better understanding

Comment: Like edekk says, you are using route model binding so just delete the line: $story = Story::find($id); because you already have the right story available. Just remember to use the story keyword "story" in your routes file.

Comment: have you tried `{{ $story }}` in your blade file and then check `dd($story);` in your controller file and check which kind of data you got in that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `link_to_action()` helper generates an actual HTML link, which is an `<a>` tag. You're therefore already using it wrong.

However the error you're getting is likely not related to this.

The best way to link to routes is using the `route()` helper:

```
<a href="{{ route('index.index', $yourParam) }}">link</a>
```

And the route definition:

```
Route::get('/someroute/{:param}', ['uses' => 'IndexController@index', 'as' => 'index.index']);
```

Note the `as` key, it assigns a name to this route. You can also call

```
Route::get(...)->name('index.index')
```

which yields the same result.

Comment: this is definitely what i would do.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but in html you're passing an integer, in controller though, function is expecting an object of Story. Just change `Story story` to `$id` and it should be good.

Anyway, can't say much more without actual error.

Comment: Laravel has route model binding, so that can work if it's the primary key.

Comment: actually true :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use it in this way: since according laravel explanation for function link_to_action first param will be controller function path, 2nd will be name and 3rd will be array of required params:

```
<a href="{{ link_to_action('StoriesController@destroy', 'destory',[$story->id]) }}" class="delete"><i class="material-icons" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
```

You can also get help from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accepting `$story` as model object so you don't have to use `Story::find()` and also you haven't define `$id` in your destroy method therefor Change your code to:

```
public function destroy(Story $story)
{
        $story->delete();

        return redirect('/stories')->with('success', 'Historic Removed');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks